For hardhat-deploy, How to upgrade contract
I can upgrade my contract with hardhat/upgrades. However, if I want to upgrade my contract with hardhat-deploy. How to deal with it?
I just want to upgrade my contract deployed before.
    const contract = await deploy('myContract', {
    contract: 'myContract',
    from: deployer,
    log: true,
    skipIfAlreadyDeployed: true,
    proxy: {
      proxyContract: 'OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy',
      execute: {
        methodName: 'initialize',
        args: ['myContract', 'myContract', deployer],
      },
    },
  });


just add upgrade method bellow
    const contract = await deploy('myContract', {
    contract: 'myContract',
    from: deployer,
    log: true,
    skipIfAlreadyDeployed: true,
    proxy: {
      proxyContract: 'OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy',
      execute: {
        onUpgrade:{
          method: "the upgrade method you want to call, it's optional"
          args: [],
        }
      },
      upgradeIndex: 1,
    },
  });

you may also need set upgradeIndex to the next number
